# Using a bitset library

Tags: c++, bitset

I am doing my first steps with C++ and with some help I have created a code to make an easy function. But I have a problem. I am using a bitset function that needs a specific library  and I don't know who to introduce this library in my code.

I have been reading some information in the net but I don't achieve to do it, so I wonder if any of you can tell me in a detailed way how to do it.

So that you make an idea I have been looking in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html#cons2 and simmilar places.

I attached my code so that you make and idea what I am doing.

Thanks in advance :)

```
// Program that converts a number from decimal to binary and show the positions where the bit of the number in binary contains 1

#include<iostream>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>
int main() {
unsigned long long dec;
std::cout << "Write a number in decimal: ";
std::cin >> dec;
boost::dynamic_bitset<> bs(64, dec);
std::cout << bs << std::endl;
for(size_t i = 0; i < 64; i++){
    if(bs[i])
        std::cout << "Position " << i << " is 1" << std::endl;
}
//system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want your `bitset` to dynamically grow, you can just use the `bitset` that comes built-in with all standards compliant C++ implementations:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main() {
  unsigned long long dec;
  std::cout << "Write a number in decimal: ";
  std::cin >> dec;
  const size_t number_of_bits = sizeof(dec) * 8;
  std::bitset<number_of_bits> bs(dec);
  std::cout << bs << std::endl;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < number_of_bits; i++) {
    if (bs[i])
      std::cout << "Position " << i << " is 1" << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

To use the `dynamic_bitset` class, you have to download the [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) libraries and add the boost folder to your compiler's include directories. If you are using the GNU C++ compiler you should something like:

```
g++ -I path/to/boost_1_46_1 mycode.cpp -o mycode
```

Comment: Thanks! I need it to grow dynamically, because of that I use this. I have already download all the Boost libraries, but I dont know where do I have to copy and introduce them. I am user Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 express. Can you give me more detailed information how to do it, please??? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @thomas: The [VC++ Directories Property Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855621.aspx) sounds like a good place to start with telling your compiler where to find header and library files.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248383/problems-with-query-time-when-accessing-to-information-stored-in-the-computer-mem/5250745#5250745) for an explanation.