# How can i have a associative array with many values

Tags: c++, arrays, associative-array

I have an album with title, year it came out and songs on the album.

My array is set up like this:

```
std::string alb_name[256]['title', 'year', 'songs'];
```

but i want the songs associative array to hold at most 20 songs.
is there an easy way to do this? i am in programming 1 class and i cant figure out a way to do it. any help is appriciated.

Comment: Why limit yourself to twenty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `struct` structures data:

```
struct Album {
    string title;
    string year;
    vector<string> tracks;
};
```

A `map` maps a value to another value:

```
map<string, Album> albums;

Album album;
album.title = "Acoustic Sketches";
album.year = "1996";
album.tracks.push_back("Metamorphosis");
album.tracks.push_back("Rivulets");
//.. etc
albums[album.title] = album;
```

Comment: this is very helpful but i am getting an error : "'vector' does not name a type"

Comment: The example isn't complete. `vector` and `map` are part of the C++ standard library. It should be in whatever documentation you are using.

Answer (score 5):

C++ has something called a `std::map` that works as an associative array.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct AlbumData
{
    int year;
    std::vector<std::string> songs;
};

std::map<std::string, AlbumData> albums;

AlbumData d;
d.year = 1966;
d.songs.push_back("A Day in the Life");
d.songs.push_back("When I'm 64");
albums["Sgt Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band"] = d;
```

etc.

Comment: i will look into this, thank you for piointing me into the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

First off, you want to use a database: [At what point is it worth using a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648802/at-what-point-is-it-worth-using-a-database/2649916#2649916)

You will want more than one associative array or map.  This will allow you to search and sort based on different fields.

For example:
Title table

```
+----------+-------+  
| ID_Title | Title |  
+----------+-------+
```

Artist table

```
+-----------+-------------+
| ID_Artist | Artist name |
+-----------+-------------+
```

Song Table

```
+-----------+----------+
| ID_Artist | ID_Title |
+-----------+----------+
```

You could set up the Song table to be sorted by artist or title.

Also search the web for "Database normal form".