# I keep getting stack overflow error and have tried fixing this for 3 days. I am creating a media library for CDs

Tags: c++, vector, stack, overflow

//Long story short, trying to do a media library, but I am at a 100% Complete loss on why I cannot get this data to work. This is my Main.cpp

```
#include "CDclass.h"

bool fills = true;//Public Switch to turn on/off autofill of "Data" classes.
bool runner = true;//Public switch that helps with the program functionality(DO NOT EDIT)

void main()
{
int decision;
unsigned int total = 5;
vector<string> titles;
vector<double> time;
string artist;
string name;

titles.resize(total);
time.resize(total);

vector<cdStorage> Data;//A vector of classes

cdStorage newCD;
Data.push_back(newCD);
Data.push_back(newCD);
Data.push_back(newCD);//This was used as a sizing test and it works.
cdStorage::cdStorage(total);

   //I used this to loop without restarting main.

while(runner == true)
{
    if(fills == true)//Autofill to get the program running
    {
        artist = "Bunny";
        name = "Bread";

        for(unsigned int x = 0; x < Data.size(); x++)
        {
            cdStorage::cdStorage(total);
            Data[x].setNewArtist(artist);
            Data[x].setNewName(name);

            for(unsigned int y = 0; y < total; y++)
            {
                titles[y] = "TestfieldBanana!";
                time[y] = 12.13;
                Data[x].setNewTitles(y, titles[y]);
                Data[x].setNewTime(y, time[y]);
            }
        }
        fills = false;
    }

    cout << Data[0].getNewArtist() << endl;
    cout << "*******************" << endl <<
            "*Media Awesomsauce*" << endl <<
            "*******************" << "\n\n" <<
            "********************" << endl <<
            "* 1: Check Library *" << endl <<
            "* 2: Add CD        *" << endl <<
            "* 3: Delete CD     *" << endl <<
            "* 4: Exit Program  *" << endl <<
            "********************" << "\n\n" <<
            "Decision:_";

    cin >> decision;
 //The majority of all of this is very self explanatory. 
    if(decision == 1)
    {
        for(unsigned int x = 0; x < Data.size(); x++)
        {
            cdStorage::cdStorage(total);
                cout << Data[x].getNewName() << "\t";
                cout << Data[x].getNewArtist() << "\t";
            for(unsigned int y = 0; y < total; y++)
            {   
                //int length = Data[x].getNewName().length();

                cout << "\t\t\t" << Data[x].getNewTitles(y);
                cout << "\t" << Data[x].getNewTime(y) << endl;
            }
        }

    }else if(decision == 2)
    {
        Data.push_back(newCD);

        system("CLS");

        cout << "What is the name of the CD: ";
        cin >> name;
        cout << "\nWhat is the name of the Artist: ";
        cin >> artist;
        cout << "\nHow many songs are there: ";
        cin >> total;

        cdStorage::cdStorage(total);
        titles.resize(total);
        time.resize(total);
        Data[Data.size()].setNewName(name);
        Data[Data.size()].setNewArtist(artist);

        cout << "What are the song titles and lengths:\n";

        for(unsigned int x = 0; x < total; x++)
        {
            cout << "Title " << x+1 << ": ";
            getline (cin, titles[x]);
            cout << "Length(Example: 3.36 for 3 mins and 36 seconds): ";
            cin >> time[x];
            cout << endl;

            Data[Data.size()].setNewTitles(x, titles[x]);
            Data[Data.size()].setNewTime(x, time[x]);
        }

    }else if(decision == 3)
    {

    }else if(decision == 4)
    {
        runner = false;

    }else
    {
        system("CLS");
        cout << "Error: You must choose a number between 1-5...\n\n";
        system("pause");
        system("CLS");
    }
  }
}
```

//This is my CDWorks.cpp

```
#include "CDclass.h"

//Constructor
cdStorage::cdStorage(){};
//Overloaded Constructor
cdStorage::cdStorage(unsigned int theTotal)
{
newTotal = theTotal;
newTitles.resize(newTotal);
newTime.resize(newTotal);
}
//Accessors
unsigned int cdStorage::getNewTotal() const
{
    return newTotal;
}

string cdStorage::getNewTitles(unsigned int x) const
{
    return newTitles[x];
}

double cdStorage::getNewTime(unsigned int x) const
{
    return newTime[x];
}

string cdStorage::getNewArtist() const
{
    return newArtist;
}

string cdStorage::getNewName() const
{
    return newName;
}

//Mutators
void cdStorage::setNewTotal(unsigned int theTotal)
{
    newTotal = theTotal;
}

void cdStorage::setNewTitles(unsigned int x, string theTitle)
{
    newTitles[x] = theTitle;
}

void cdStorage::setNewTime(unsigned int x, double theTime)
{
    newTime[x] = theTime;
}

void cdStorage::setNewArtist(string theArtist)
{
    newArtist = theArtist;
}

void cdStorage::setNewName(string theName)
{
    newName = theName;
}
//Destructor
cdStorage::~cdStorage(){}
```

//This is my CDClass.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

#ifndef CDCLASS_H
#define CDCLASS_H

class cdStorage
{
private:
unsigned int newTotal;
vector<string> newTitles;
vector<double> newTime;
string newArtist;
string newName;

public:
//Constructor
cdStorage();
//Overloaded Constructor
cdStorage(unsigned int);
//Destructor
~cdStorage();
//Accessors
unsigned int getNewTotal() const;
string getNewTitles(unsigned int) const;//The integer is to track which element needs returned.
double getNewTime(unsigned int) const;
string getNewArtist() const;
string getNewName() const;
//Mutators
void setNewTotal(unsigned int);
void setNewTitles(unsigned int, string);
void setNewTime(unsigned int, double);
void setNewArtist(string);
void setNewName(string);
};

#endif
```

Comment: Where is the stack overflow occurring? Use `int main`, too, and never put `using namespace xxx;` in headers like that.

Comment: Please edit the title to indicate the problem you're having, not how hard you've been persevering. If you run the program under a debugger, does it break at the line the problem occurs, and if so, what line is that on?

Comment: You should really consider using a database than writing your own: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648802/at-what-point-is-it-worth-using-a-database/2649916#2649916

Comment: You should create a new class containing new titles and new times.  This will prevent errors where `newTitles[x]` does not have a matching `newTimes[x]` or the relationship is not correct.

Comment: If you want to write your own database, I suggest placing all the data into a `std::vector` and using a `std::map` as an index table.  An index table allows you to have more than one ordering scheme without having to resort the original data.  For example, you could sort by artist or album title.

Comment: You don't need to compare `bool` variables to `true` or `false` in an if expression.

Comment: The `for` loop in the `if (fills == true)` section will not be executed if the `Data` vector is empty, because empty has a size of 0 and 0 is not less than 0.

Answer (score 2):

`Data[Data.size()]` is accessing outside the vector `Data`, which is undefined behaviour, so anything can happen.

Also, I don't know what you think repeatedly calling `cdStorage::cdStorage(total);` does, but it doesn't do anything except create a new (anonymous) object that is immediately thrown away.

All the `cdStorage`s you have created were created using the default (parameterless) constructor, which leaves `newTotal` totally uninitialized, and the `vector`s are both empty. You can't modify them by calling a constructor afterwards (I suspect that is what yo're trying to accomplish).

Since the vectors are empty, when you say e.g. `newTitles[x] = theTitle;`, you're accessing invalid memory, which means that your program, again, has undefined behaviour.

It's very difficult to say whether these are the cause of your problems, but you should probably fix them first before you go on.

You should probably review the chapter on constructors and instance creation in your Fine Book.

Comment: Ah yes, well spotted, I stopped when I saw `Data[Data.size()]` and didn't get as far as reading `CDWorks.cpp` to see that `Data[x].setNewTitles(y, titles[y]);` is also an out-of-bounds access

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>     Data[Data.size()].setNewName(name);
> ```

This accesses past the end of the vector, it only has `Data.size()` elements, starting from zero.  **This is undefined behaviour** and probably causing the problem.

It may not be the problem, but as you haven't said where the error happens it's hard to know. You have the failing program, you should be able to debug it and say where it blows up ... you've had three days to learn to use a debugger!

Until you know what you're doing I suggest you stop using `[x]` to access vectors and switch to using the `at(x)` function, which does the same thing but checks that `x` is a valid index and not larger than the vector's size.  If you'd done that then you'd have got an exception at the first problem, instead of undefined behaviour and a stack overflow.

There are a number of other issues...

Put your include guards at the top of the file, not after other headers.

Never put `using namespace` at namespace scope in a header.

You keep doing this:

> `cdStorage::cdStorage(total);`

What's that supposed to do and why do you keep doing it?

You should use member initializers in constructors instead of altering them in the constructor body:

```
cdStorage::cdStorage(unsigned int theTotal)
{
newTotal = theTotal;
newTitles.resize(newTotal);
newTime.resize(newTotal);
}
```

i.e. do this instead:

```
cdStorage::cdStorage(unsigned int theTotal)
: newTotal(theTotal), newTitles(theTotal), newTime(theTotal)
{ }
```