# Implementing a library management system on C++ using data structures

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am working on a project to implement a library management system on c++ using data structures. I need some tips on what data structure to use where in the most efficient way.

The implementation i am adopting is:

1. Using a priority queue in the form of a tree. The queue will contain categories of books & each category will be assigned a unique number.
2. Inside each node of a tree, there will be a linked list that will contain books of that specific category.
3. Inside each node of a linked list there is a binary tree. This binary tree contains students who have issued that specific book in the node of list. Binary tree is sorted according to the registration number student will enter when he issues a books.

Any other ideas??

Answer (score 0):

**Use a database, don't reinvent your own.**

See my reasoning: [At what point is it worth using a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648802/at-what-point-is-it-worth-using-a-database/2649916#2649916)

Read up on "database normal forms" and "index tables".

I decided on my project, I'd rather spend time working with the data rather than rewriting a database.

For database selection, search StackOverflow for "[C++] which database".